# C# Windows Application LOC_Counter

Tags: c#, windows

Hey I want to create a windows application that should display the **total lines**, **Blank lines and commented lines**. I am able to calculate Total Lines, Can any one help me with the logic for blank lines and commented lines!

I want to count the Lines Of Code, for any file, i.e .html, .css, .cs, etc.

Also if possible I want the result to be exported to a Excel File!

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Line_Counter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { 
         OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            textbox1.Clear();
            textbox2.Clear();
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string strFilename = ofd.FileName;
                textbox1.Text = Path.GetFileName(strFilename);
                StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(strFilename);

                int nLineCount = 0;
                while (sr.ReadLine() != null)
                {
                    nLineCount++;    
                }


                textbox1.Text = nLineCount.ToString("0,0");
                sr.Close();
            }
        }

        private void txtFileName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }


    }
```

}

---

I want more text boxes that should display count of blank lines, Commented lines, and finally the total count (i.e. subtracting the no. of blank lines and commented lines from total no of lines)

If Possible single button_click for each or all in one.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKmbj.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried, and where exactly are you stuck? The code you posted only counts overall lines...

Comment: Yes, I need to count the blank Lines as well as the commented lines.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 if (str != null && str.Length > 0 && (str.Length > 2 && str.Substring(0, 2) != "//") && (str.Length > 3 && str.Substring(0, 4) != "<!--"))

I am using this logic but I need help on how to display them to a textbox using a button_click

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace LOC_Counter
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void getFileList(string directory)
        {
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(directory);

            foreach (string dir in dirs)
            {
                getFileList(dir);
            }
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {

                StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(file);

                int nLineCount = 0;
                string str = string.Empty;
                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    str = sr.ReadLine();
                    if (str != null && str.Length > 0 && (str.Length > 2 && str.Substring(0, 2) != "//") && (str.Length > 3 && str.Substring(0, 4) != "<!--"))
                    nLineCount++;
                }
                lstbxResult.Items.Add(file + "              Line count - " + nLineCount);

            }



        }

        private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog();

            if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                lstbxResult.Items.Clear();
                getFileList(FBD.SelectedPath);

            }
        }

        public static void ExportToExcel(ListBox lst, string excel_file)
        {
            int cols;
            //open file
            StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(excel_file);

            //write rows to excel file
            for (int i = 0; i < (lst.Items.Count - 1); i++)
            {
                wr.Write(lst.Items[i].ToString() + "\t");

                wr.WriteLine();
            }

            //close file
            wr.Close();
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```